# Is it possible to find out an app download / installation date on iOS?

Tags: iphone, applications, history, ios

Is there a way to find out the exact date of installation of an application that was added to my phone?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. I edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it in a separate post. Thanks!

Comment: There is an application call [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). From this tool (even with the free version) you can achieve what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

On iPhone (iOS 11.0.3): 
Settings > iTunes & App Store: Apple ID: View Apple ID > Purchase History -- tap "Last 90 Days" to expand view to include previous years.

Shows free and paid purchases by date.

Answer (score 1):

In the older software, there is no way of finding out exactly when an app was purchased, but in the latest software, you can go to the App Store and select Updates, then click on the top right to go to Purchased and see if the app was purchased (paid or free) and the date of install.The list is sorted by newest on the top.

Answer (score 1):

There are some dates you can see in iTunes.  Perhaps apps downloaded directly to the iPhone are not there?  I don't know.

[image: itunes]

Comment: ... and the new iTunes 12.7 no longer syncs apps to iOS, so this answer is out of date.

Comment: I used [this osxdaily.com guide](http://osxdaily.com/2017/09/17/downgrade-itunes-12-7-to-itunes-12-6/) to downgrade to 12.6, I do now see the Apps menu, but it doesn't have any dates on it. Probably because I installed them from within the device

Answer (score 0):

App Store functionality has been removed entirely in iTunes 12.7 (after years of their slowly weaning devices off of it), so the answer pointed out by GEdgar, while true, won’t be around much longer.

As for finding a download date, the closest you can get, as far as I know, would be looking through your iTunes receipts under Store > Account > Purchase History.

Even then, this is subject to Apple’s batching together of iTunes purchases to cut down on credit card processing fees, so this will only give you a general idea of the purchase date, with precision to about a week or shorter. And of course, this is only the **purchase** date, not the (most recent) installation date. The two may be different, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this on my iPad mini 4 (software version 14.4.1) so I thought I'd tell how I did it, I think it works about the same with iPhones:

AppStore > tap the account image on top right corner > Purchased

This shows a list of all apps you've ever donwloaded and the download dates.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a game you can go to Game Center to find out the download date.

Answer (score -1):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088
This link may be helpful for anyone who comes across this more recently. Upon further research, I am fairly sure that your purchases include free apps, too. Apparently you are also able to view hidden purchases by going to "Account" in iTunes and going to "iTunes in the Cloud" (if that still exists in the newest version of iTunes. Hope this helps.

- Jasmine